# Successfully started Zookeeper server but failed to start broker server

Tags: apache-kafka

I am running Apache Kafka on my local machine (MacOS). I have the `bin/` path setup. I try to start kafka by:

1. Step one, start Zookeeper:
   `zookeeper-server-start.sh kafka_2.13-3.0.0/config/zookeeper.properties`
   This step is successful.
2. Then, I try to start broker server by:

`kafka-server-start.sh kafka_2.13-3.0.0/config/server.properties`

The broker server is not started, I see following error:

```
org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Failed to acquire lock on file .lock in /Users/john/kafka_2.13-3.0.0/data/kafka. A Kafka instance in another process or thread is using this directory.
    at kafka.log.LogManager.$anonfun$lockLogDirs$1(LogManager.scala:241)
    at scala.collection.StrictOptimizedIterableOps.flatMap(StrictOptimizedIterableOps.scala:117)
    at scala.collection.StrictOptimizedIterableOps.flatMap$(StrictOptimizedIterableOps.scala:104)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArraySeq.flatMap(ArraySeq.scala:37)
```

Based on the above error log, it complains that a Kafka instance in another process or thread is using this directory `/Users/john/kafka_2.13-3.0.0/data/kafka`. But I can't think of any other process using it on my Macbook.

How can I figure out which process is using that directory, or how can I get rid of this error so that I can start the broker server?

Comment: Personally, I suggest using homebrew or Docker for running Kafka